# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-\frac{n^2+x^2}{n} }\sin{(nx)}$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

As part of preparing for an exam, I would like to confirm with you my solution to the exercise below (if you can prove it in a different way, I would like to know).

Thank you!

---

### Question

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n2^{-\frac{n^2+x^2}{n} }\sin{(nx)}$ uniformly convergent for $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

---

### My attempt

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Define $u_n(x)=n2^{-\frac{n^2+x^2}{n} }\sin{(nx)}$. Notice that:
$$|u_n(x)|= | n2^{-\frac{n^2+x^2}{n} }\sin{(nx)}| \le \left| n \frac{1}{2^{n+\frac{x^2}{n}}}\right| \le  n \frac{1}{2^{n}} $$

From [WeierstrassM-Test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassM-Test.html) we finish the proof.

---

Is there a good way to guess if it's convergent or not in advance?

Comment: Please be more specific, don't just ask for a confirmation of your proof. – See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4597/42969 and https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info

Comment: Looks good to me.